# Find Percentage of each class for every ID

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, pandas-groupby

I am working with a data frame that has 20 ids and for each Id, there are about 10-15 stores, and each store is assigned a status (Zero, Negative and Positive).

Data:

```
data = 
ID      STORE  STATUS           
100001  1      zero 
100001  2      positive 
100001  3      zero 
100001  4      negative     
100001  5      zero    
100001  6      zero 
100001  7      positive 
100001  8      negative 
....
```

**Problem:**

I would like to find out what percentage of stores are zeros/ positive/negative for each id.

My attempt:

```
zero = 0

for item in data['ID'].unique():
    items = data[data['ID']==item]
    lenght = len(items)
    print(lenght)
    for index, i in items.iterrows():
        if i['STATUS'] == 'Zero':
            zero += 1
            pct = zero/lenght
    items['PCT'] = zero/lenght
    print(items)
```

My result from code above:

```
ID      STORE  STATUS.    PCT           
100001  1      zero       0.5
100001  2      positive   0.5
100001  3      zero       0.5
100001  4      negative   0.5
100001  5      zero       0.5
100001  6      zero       0.5
100001  7      positive   0.5
100001  8      negative   0.5
```

Expected result :

```
ID      STORE  STATUS.    PCT           
100001  1      zero       0.5
100001  2      positive   0.25
100001  3      zero       0.5
100001  4      negative   0.25
100001  5      zero       0.5
100001  6      zero       0.5
100001  7      positive   0.25
100001  8      negative   0.25
```

Comment: If you're using explicit loops with pands, you're often doing something wrong. Use its built-in grouping methods.

Comment: I wonder if this is what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50169311/getting-percentage-and-count-python

Comment: Thank you @Mark, that helped.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you want to transform the share of each status across stores. Then you can `groupby` "ID" and "Status" and count how many stores are in each group and transform it for the column and divide it by the length:

```
df['PCT'] = df.groupby(['ID','STATUS'])['STORE'].transform('count') / df.groupby('ID')['ID'].transform('count')
```

Output:

```
       ID  STORE    STATUS   PCT
0  100001      1      zero  0.50
1  100001      2  positive  0.25
2  100001      3      zero  0.50
3  100001      4  negative  0.25
4  100001      5      zero  0.50
5  100001      6      zero  0.50
6  100001      7  positive  0.25
7  100001      8  negative  0.25
```